# Odoo add custom log handler

Tags: odoo

I want to add custom events on errors in odoo like emails sending or something like that.

```
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

Maybe like that i can add my method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place in any module:

```
class MyHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        if record:
            if record.levelname == 'ERROR':
                print 'CUSTOM ACTION'

mh = MyHandler()
logging.getLogger().addHandler(mh)
```